# Google Analytics API: What is the ´YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN´?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Yes, what is it and where does it go? I see examples like:

```
    For example, the following example shows the request and the collection returned in the response:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts
Authorization: /* YOUR_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN */
```

From http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/v3/mgmtRest.html

I'm completely lost here! How am I supposed to input the access token there? And what is it? My google API password?

Answer (score 0):

You have to exchange the `code` for the `access token` **OR**, if you are trying to get it, the `refresh token`.

Then you call the google api of choice with either the `access token` or the `refresh token`.

See the following tutorials:

[Authenticating with OAuth 2.0 for Google API Access with PHP](http://www.jensbits.com/2011/12/20/authenticating-with-oauth-2-0-for-google-api-access-with-php/)

[Google API Requests with OAuth 2.0 Access Token](http://www.jensbits.com/2011/12/29/google-api-requests-with-oauth-2-0-access-token/)

[Google API Offline Access Using OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token](http://www.jensbits.com/2012/01/09/google-api-offline-access-using-oauth-2-0-refresh-token/)

Comment: i can't make any of those examples work... is this supposed to be that hard? :(

Comment: @luqita The examples are step-by-step and include code. What exactly was the problem you were having running the examples?